Sitecore - Browser-Based Personalization
I have one client requirement where I need to implement different "browser based personalization". Means in different browsers we will show different products. Currently working on Sitecore 10.2 with headless. Is there anyone implemented the same thing? Please let me know how can we achieve.
Any help is appreciated.

There are several ways of doing this - hard to say which is best not knowing all the details. Are you using SSR of SSG? How do you want to edit the personalization?  ...

Are you using Sitecore Personalize or xDB with XP? What is your personalization tooling?

Based on my understanding, you want to implement browser-based personalization to display different products on different browsers.
To achieve this, you need to create separate rules for each browser. In these newly created rules, you should specify the names of the different browsers.
Additionally, you'll need to create distinct data source items and assign them to each rule according to the products you want to show on each browser.
You can create your personalization rules in the Rendering Personalize section.

As shown in images You can create your new role on click of plus button. After that click on Edit rule where you set your rule accordingly. Or in the content section you can assign your data source.

Hope this helps!!!

Thank you for your detailed response!

You can create a Programmable inside the Decision model to get the information about the browser. This decision model can then be binded to the web experiences to personalize the experience depending on the browser.
Inside the programmable, details about the user-agent can be fetched using below code.
const getUserAgent = function(){
  if (request && request.requestDetails && request.requestDetails.headers && request.requestDetails.headers['User-Agent']) {
   var userAgent = request.requestDetails.headers['User-Agent'];
   if (userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
        return "Microsoft Edge";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
        return "Chrome";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
        return "Firefox";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
        return "Safari";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1) {
        return "Opera";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Trident") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) 
    {
        return "Internet Explorer";
    }
  }
  return "";
}

Based on the browser details returned from the above programmable, can be used to return different products depending on the browser.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

This is only going to work if they are using Sitecore Personalize. This will not work with XP Personalization
